# Move files from one folder to another folder having the same hierarchy and folder name using batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file, directory, hierarchy, move

So, I wish to move the files under all converted folders from the main Source folder to another Output folder having the same hierarchy.

```
Source
   -done
   -converted
   -folder1
      -done
      -converted
      -folder11
         -done
         -converted
   -folder2
      -done
      -converted
```

TO

```
Output
   (files from converted folder)
   -folder1
      (files from converted folder)
      -folder11
         (files from converted folder)
   -folder2
      (files from converted folder)
```

I'm new to batch scripting so, I would really appreciate if you can help me in some way.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please show us the code you already have.

Comment: In conjunction to what mfm4aa said, check out [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET source=c:\sourcedir
SET destroot=c:\destdir
SET cdtl=0
:loploop
SET /a cdtl+=1
FOR /f "tokens=%cdtl%*delims=\" %%i IN ("%source%") DO IF NOT "%%j"=="" GOTO loploop
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
    ' dir /b/s/ad "%source%\converted" '
    ) DO CALL :movedest "%%~dpni%"
)
GOTO :eof

:movedest
SET destdir=%~1
FOR /f "tokens=%cdtl%*delims=\" %%d IN (%1) DO SET destdir=%destroot%\%%e
ECHO MD "%destdir%" 2>NUL
ECHO MOVE /y "%~1\*.*" "%destdir%\"
GOTO :eof
```

The `ECHO`s in the penultimate two lines simply SHOW the operations that are proposed. After you've verified that's what you want to do, simply delete the `ECHO` keyword to perform the move.

Note that the `/y` switch in the `MOVE` command will overwrite any existing destination version of a file.